# Refactoring if else statement

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

**Here is my method:**

```
Object.entries(query).forEach(([key, value]) => {
  if (key === 'team_ids') {
    if (typeof value === 'string') {
      this.items.push(this.$store.getters.teamById(value));
    } else {
      value.forEach((itemId) => {
        this.items.push(this.$store.getters.teamById(itemId));
      });
    }
else if (key === 'close_ids') {
    if (typeof value === 'string') {
      this.items.push(this.$store.getters.closeFriendsById(value));
    } else {
      value.forEach((friendId) => {
        this.items.push(this.$store.getters.closeFriendsById(friendId));
      });
    }
  } else {
    if (key === 'name') this.name = value;
    if (key === 'patr') this.patr= value;  
  }
});
```

*I am trying to refactor it but now i'm stumped...*
It don't looks good.
Any advice?

Comment: What do you want to refactor and why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can refactor *if statements* with a *switch statement*.

Try this:

```
Object.entries(query).forEach(([key, value]) => {
  switch(key) {
    case 'name' : 
      this.name = value; break;
    case 'patr' : 
      this.patr = value; break;
    default:
      let getterMap = {
        'team_ids': 'teamById',
        'close_ids': 'closeFriendsById'
      }
      if(Array.isArray(value)) {
        value.forEach((itemId) => {
          this.items.push(this.$store.getters[getterMap[key]](itemId));
        });
      } else {
        this.items.push(this.$store.getters[getterMap[key]](value));
      }
      break;
  }
});
```

You can add more keys in getterMap if you want to.

Answer (score 0):

It's not bad, You have ternary operators which make code cleaner and if statements are shortened. However, to if you want to refactor it, you should provide some info about the logic, because it is important in refactoring.